# Can't install python libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

got a new laptop (MacBook Air with Catalina) and installed python 3 thru Homebrew.

When trying to install and run some libraries in a jupyter notebook (also installed thru Homebrew) like:

```
!pip3 install pandas
```

and then:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Same thing with numpy, matplotlib, bs4, etc. Even though when I rerun the !pip3 install something I get the message:

> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.19.2)

When I run:

```
!which python3
!which pip3
```

I get

> /usr/local/bin/python3

> /usr/local/bin/pip3

is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You would need to restart the kernel in jupyter before importing

Comment: Try running `python3 -m pip list` and see if they are installed

Comment: Already restarted kernel and nothing.

Comment: running `python3 -m pip list` I get

Package         Version
--------------- -------
beautifulsoup4  4.9.3
bs4             0.0.1
numpy           1.19.2
pandas          1.1.3
pip             20.2.3
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2020.1
setuptools      49.2.0
six             1.15.0
soupsieve       2.0.1
wheel           0.34.2

Comment: check in a jupiter: print(sys.version) which version it use

Comment: Its the only python 3 version installed: 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:48:26) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)]

Comment: import in terminal do work but not in jupyter notebook. Any ideas why?? please help

Comment: Problem seemed to be installing jupyter thru homebrew. Uninstalled it, and then reinstalled it with pip and now everything is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seemed to be installing jupyter thru homebrew. Uninstalled it, and then reinstalled it with pip and now everything is working

Answer (score 0):

I’ve catch like this problem
It helped me that:

Uninstall python
And install python
Then reboot system

I guess your Catalina use 3 version py3 this time
It’s need realias

I guess on Mac OS is better to use pip3 by terminal.